# Elixir: add key to map if not present, else raise error

Tags: elixir

In Elixir, is there a function which will add a key to a map if it is not already present, and otherwise raise an error?

I know of `put_new` which adds a key if it is not present, but if the key is present, it doesn't raise an error, just ignores the new value.

Answer (score 4):

[`Map.update/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Map.html#update/4) can be used to get what you want in one line.

> Updates the `key` in `map` with the given function.
>
> If `key` is present in `map` then the existing value is passed to `fun` and its result is used as the updated value of `key`. If key is not present in `map`, `default` is inserted as the value of `key`. The default value will not be passed through the update function.

The `fun` update function will only be called if the key is present, so we can just throw your error there.

```
Map.update(my_map, :key, some_value, fn _ -> throw "Already have a value!" end)
```

The argument to `fun` is the *current* value of the key, so you can use that to provide a more detailed error message if you like.

Answer (score 2):

`Map.put_new!/3`, which does exactly what you describe, was [proposed in March 2017](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/pull/5917) but the idea was rejected because, quoting lexmag:

> `put_new` and `put_new!` pair behaves differently from `!`-paired functions, I'm not sure if it's good thing to break expectations in that case.

There is [a bit more information](https://groups.google.com/g/elixir-lang-core/c/ZjkRPB27sho/m/ojxbzDrACgAJ) on the `elixir-lang-core` mailing list, quoting José Valim:

> I believe the concern here is that while all functions raise when the key does not exist, the proposed put_new! raises when the key exists. It is how put_new! should behave... but it is a different behaviour than the one that already exists, highlighted by the fact a new exception would have to be added.